# Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "MathParser.org-mXparser.Net46"

Tags: c#, исключения, dll, math, library

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

> - Импортирую библиотеку так, "Добавить > ссылка"
> - Версии .Net совпадают
> - Запускал с отладкой и без отладки, результат один и тот-же

**Код** :

```
using org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MathLinearParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Expression e = new Expression("2-(32-4)/(23+4/5)-(2-4)*(4+6-98.2)+4");
            mXparser.consolePrintln("Res: " + e.getExpressionString() + " = " + e.calculate());
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception** :

> Необработанное исключение: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Не удалось
>   загрузить файл или сборку "MathParser.org-mXparser.Net46,
>   Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0fbab7add73ed6e2"
>   либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить следующие варианты:

1. Установите библиотеку в проект через NuGet
2. Скачайте исходники и добавьте их в проект как зависимый проект (получите два проекта в решении и поставьте ссылку на внутренний проект.

Ибо воспроизвести Вашу ошибку не удалось.

И напишите вашу систему и IDE.

Comment: Windows 10, Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Comment: Смогли из нугет его (пакет) забрать?

Comment: Я зашёл в диспетчер пакетов и минут пять кручу список, не могу найти этот пакет

Comment: Его нет в диспетчере пакетов. Это пакет сделан не Microsoft. Его надо искать в NuGet. В меню проект выберете "Управление пакетами NuGet"

Comment: Всё, спасибо :D